# How to yield a request within a recursive generator function?

Tags: node.js, recursion, yield, koa

I have created a generator function that recursively checks a string and returns a parsed output.  I am trying to make a request within the generator using koa-request however, it is returning undefined.

```
var parseUserExpression = function *() {
    var body = yield bodyParser.json(this);

    var fnString = body.ts;

    var res = yield parseRulesAndFunctions(fnString, null);

    this.body = res;
};

// Recursive function
var parseRulesAndFunctions = function *(aStr, start) {
    var res;
    start = start || 0;

    var fnDetails = getFnDetails(aStr, start);

    if (fnDetails.fnType === 'run') {
        var url = yield request(fnDetails.url);

        res = aStr.slice(0, fnDetails.startIndex) + 'yield request(' + fnDetails.fnName + ',' + fnDetails.fnParams + aStr.slice(fnDetails.endIndex);
    }

    // Recurse
    if (res.indexOf('call') === -1 && res.indexOf('run') === -1) {
        return res;
    }
    return parseRulesAndFunctions(res, fnDetails.paramEnd).next();
}
```

Returns the Promise instead of a string when yielding the request(fnDetails.url).

Comment: Why is that result string containing code? Just curious.

Comment: It's a tool that will allow non devs to create simple tools through our UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are recursively calling a generator function, you must yield all results from the generator. You can do that using [`yield*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*). Only returning a single `.next()` result won't do it.

You're looking for

```
return yield* parseRulesAndFunctions(res, fnDetails.paramEnd);
```

Of course, you could easily convert your tail-recursive function into a loop.